# Export a webgrid to pdf asp mvc razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, razor

How to export a webgrid to a .pdf file in an mvc .net web application?

Comment: to start with see [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1694235.aspx/1?Export+my+table+data+to+PDf+in+Asp+net) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1694235.aspx/1?Export+my+table+data+to+PDf+in+Asp+net)

Comment: all of'em are "code behind" :/

Comment: @Yasser mvc it's mentioned!

Comment: You can take a look at [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). I used that tool to create pdf documents from html tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of ways to do it:

- You can use [RazorPDF](http://www.nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF) as mentioned in the previous response
- You can use [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa). Which works very fast, but you need permissions to run the server on Full Trust, as the PDF transformation occurs on an executable file
- You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which would be the most difficult/cumbersome to implement, but at the same time you have all the flexibility to write the PDF document as you wish

Hope that helps-

Answer (score 0):

For complete reference, please follow  [How to Export Webgrid to PDF in MVC4 Application](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/08/how-to-export-webgrid-to-pdf-in-mvc4.html)

Create an action link to your view page

```
<div>
     Export Data : @Html.ActionLink("Export to PDF","GETPdf","Webgrid")
</div>
```

then create an MVC Action for export webgrid data to pdf file. Here iTextSharp.dll used for export pdf file.

```
public FileStreamResult GETPdf()
    {
        List<CustomerInfo> all = new List<CustomerInfo>();
        using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            all = dc.CustomerInfoes.ToList();
        }

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: all, canPage: false, canSort: false);
        string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(
                columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("CustomerID", "Customer ID"),
                        grid.Column("CustomerName", "Customer Name"),
                        grid.Column("Address", "Address"),
                        grid.Column("City", "City"),
                        grid.Column("PostalCode", "Postal Code")
                    )
                ).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table{ border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate; }</style>", gridHtml);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }
```